# Sending email with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send a view with array `foreach` (to fill table) in a email.

```
Mail::send(['estancias.plantilla'], ['estancias'=>$array], function ($message) use ($from,$to) {
     $message->from($from)->to($to);
});
```

Return

> Undefined offset: 1, but im not sure what is the error.

The data Array is ok.

So the question is Why i can't send this view with data in a email?

**EDIT:**

The DD of array unfold:

```
Collection {#2048 ▼
      #items: array:1082 [▼
        0 => Inventory {#2049 ▼
          #connection: "oracle_da"
          +table: "INVENTORY"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:7 [ …7]
          #original: array:7 [ …7]
          #relations: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
          #dates: []
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
        }
        1 => Inventory {#2050 ▶}
        2 => Inventory {#2051 ▶}
        3 => Inventory {#2052 ▶}
        4 => Inventory {#2053 ▶}
        5 => Inventory {#2054 ▶}
        6 => Inventory {#2055 ▶}
        7 => Inventory {#2056 ▶}
        8 => Inventory {#2057 ▶}
        9 => Inventory {#2058 ▶}
        10 => Inventory {#2059 ▶}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Estancias.plantilla

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Estancias</title>
    <style>
    td,th{
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $codigoActual="";
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Listado de estancias</h1>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th width="col-lg-1">Código</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">In Date</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">Cntr No</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">VSL</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">Call Year</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">Call Seq</th>
                <th width="col-lg-1">Diferencia</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($estancias->sortBy('agent_code')  as $estancia)
                @if($codigoActual==$estancia->agent_code)
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{isset ($estancia->in_date)?\Carbon\Carbon::parse($estancia->in_date)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'):''  }}</td>
                    <td>{!!$estancia->cntr_no ? $estancia->cntr_no:''!!}</td>
                    <td>{!!$estancia->vsl_cd ? $estancia->vsl_cd:''!!}</td>
                    <td>{!!$estancia->call_year ? $estancia->call_year:''!!}</td>
                    <td>{!!$estancia->call_seq ? $estancia->call_seq:''!!}</td>
                    <td>{!!$estancia->diferencia ? $estancia->diferencia:''!!}</td>
                </tr>
                @else  
                <?php  $codigoActual=$estancia->agent_code; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$codigoActual}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                @endif
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Se han encontrado <b>{{count($estancias)}}</b> elementos.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the view and results of  `{{ dd($array) }}`

Comment: An undefined offset error in PHP happens when you try to access an array item using an index that does not exist. Please re-verify that the array is ok and the indexes that you are trying to access are defined for sure.

Comment: The dd of array return Collection {#2048 ▼
  #items: array:1082 [▶]
}

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre please unfold all elements and post it somewhere. Also, show the view.

Comment: show `estancias.plantilla` this view code

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: I would check that you're following the correct documentation for the laravel version. I remember there was a big difference between 4.2 and 5.0 with Mail?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `parenthesis` from first parameter.

```
Mail::send('estancias.plantilla', ['estancias'=>$array], function ($message) use ($from,$to) {
    $message->from($from)->to($to);
});
```

Comment: This return Maximum execution time of 400 seconds exceeded.

Comment: that's something else, not related to this problems, may be its taking much time, may be you could make a event for sending mail which implements ShouldQueue

Comment: or you could use mailables, see this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#generating-mailables

Comment: Can´t use it. I use in my project Laravel 5.0.

Comment: then use event listener to send email which implement ShouldQueue, see this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events

Comment: in your config, try editing the `max_execution_time`

Comment: may be you should do this in your controller, view code should be free of logic